# Having unique constraints for custom fields in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have created a custom post type with some unique meta fields using the `schema` syntax.

```php
function register_menu_items_schema(): array
{
    return array(
            'single' => true,
            'type' => 'array',
            'show_in_rest' => array(
                    'schema' => array(
                            'items' => array(
                                    'type' => 'array',
                                    'properties' => array(
                                            'menuItemId' => array (
                                                    'type' => 'int'
                                            ),
                                            'parentMenuItemId' => array(
                                                    'type' => 'int'
                                            ),
                                            'pageId' => array(
                                                    'type' => 'int'
                                            ),
                                            'navigationLabel' => array(
                                                    'type' => 'string'
                                            ),
                                            'navigationLink' => array(
                                                    'type' => 'string'
                                            )
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )
    );
}


    register_post_meta('country', 'footerMenuItems', register_menu_items_schema());
    register_post_meta('country', 'headerMenuItems', register_menu_items_schema());
```

This works fins as expected. But i want to ensure that some of these fields are unique, so there are no duplicates added.

The only solution i could think of was to query all and filter manually every time a CTP would be persisted, but this seems very inefficient.